# I am studying type modifiers in c and when i am facing some problem

Tags: c, sizeof

I am trying to check the size of long using size_of() opertaor it shows 4 byte which should be 8.the problem is only for long modifier. Is someone having any solution for this?

I am getting size of long modifier in vs code as 4 byte, but the expected size is 8byte.

Comment: The size of all integers are compiler and platform dependent. The only one that have a fixed size is `char`, which will always be `1` no matter the actual bit word size.

Comment: As for your "problem", are you building with MSVC? It will use a 32-bit `long` even on 64-bit systems.

Comment: Who says it should be 8? It's 4 on Windows and 8 elsewhere. In general, the C standard allows types to have different sizes within certain limits, but in practice usually only `long` varies.

Comment: yes i am using MSVC– @Some programmer dude

Comment: got it @HolyBlackCat ,i am very new to code so just have partial info about size

Comment: The sizes go `int` <= `long` <= `long long`. The `long` type is useful when `int` is 16 bits. Elsewhere it can cause confusion and IMO is unnecessary and should be avoided.

Comment: Note that "64-bit" usually refers to the compiler and the size of pointers. I have a 32-bit and a 64-bit compiler running on a 64-bit machine.